# Cannot see product's revenue in Google Analytics EE

Tags: php, google-analytics, e-commerce, measurement-protocol, enhanced-ecommerce

Currently I implement Google Analytics Enhanced Ecommerce, and there's an issue with purchase tracking.

I track purchases from PHP backend, so I use [Google Analytics Measurement Protocol library](https://github.com/theiconic/php-ga-measurement-protocol#order-tracking-with-enhanced-e-commerce) (link leads to corresponding readme section) for PHP. And everything works fine, except one thing: revenue from purchases is displayed in *Sales Performance* section, but for some reason it is **not** displayed with corresponding product in *Product List Performance* section (but number of purchases is displayed correctly).

Please have a look at the picture:

[image]

P.S. Quantity is missing too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I got it.

Product's quantity in my requests was set to `NULL` by mistake. Thats why product's price was not calculated in revenue. Not it works as supposed to.